# Trying to pickle a list in python

Tags: python, pickle

Trying to save a list of integers in python using pickle, following the exact method given to me by many sources, and I'm still encountering the same error.  Here's the simplified version:

```
import pickle
a=[0,4,8,[3,5]]
with open(blah.pickle, 'wb') as b:
    pickle.dump(a,b)
```

And I always get the error:

```
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: okay I forgot the quotes to make 'blah.pickle' a string, which was stupid of me, but it's still going wrong after fixing that.  Now, with the same code with that fix, I get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dump'

Comment: The code you posted works with the fix.  There must be something else odd you are doing in your actual code.  You should ask another question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make it a string:

```
import pickle
a=[0,4,8,[3,5]]
with open('blah.pickle', 'wb') as b:
    pickle.dump(a,b)
```

Without the quotes, Python is looking for the variable called `blah` and trying to get the `pickle` attribute of that object.  Since you have never defined `blah` as a variable, you get a `NameError`.

Comment: I still got error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_pickle'

Answer (score 0):

You never defined a variable `blah` with a `pickle` attribute.  If you meant the constant string `'blah.pickle'` to be the **name** of the resulting file, put **quotes** around it, of course...!  I.e:

```
with open('blah.pickle', 'wb') as b:
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method that I found on kite.com and it worked perfectly for me.

```
sample_list = [1, 2, 3]
file_name = "sample.pkl"

open_file = open(file_name, "wb")
pickle.dump(sample_list, open_file)
open_file.close()

open_file = open(file_name, "rb")
loaded_list = pickle.load(open_file)
open_file.close()

print(loaded_list)

#Outputs [1, 2, 3]
```